# Can I get SDL Tridion Virtual Machine for my own purpose without license cost?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Is it possible to get SDL Tridion VMware for my own to learn? I've seen somewhere in the forum (in one of Nuno's post) may be stackoverflow or tridon forum like I can get the VMWare from SDL Tridion if I work for SDL project.

I checked with SDL Customer Support, but they don't provide any :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common question, I wrote a blog over 2 years ago about getting individual developer environments here:

http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/06/The-Fifth-Environment.aspx

To the best of my knowledge (as @Ram and @Nuno state) there is currently no way to get an evaluation license without being a Employee, Partner, Client or SDL Tridion MVP

Comment: The situation has since changed. Anyone can apply to SDL to get a Developer license.

Answer (score 5):

As I did say in my blog, this is how you can get a Tridion License:

- You work for [SDL](http://www.sdl.com/) (SDL Employee)
- You work for a [SDL (WCM) Partner](http://www.sdl.com/community/partner/partner-programs/tridion-partners/)
- You work for a SDL (WCM) Customer
- You are a [SDL Tridion MVP](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/mvp_award/index.aspx)

So, the options didn't change. If any of the above applies to you, you can get a license.

Nuno

Comment: You work for a SDL (WCM) Customer, does this mean customer license?

Comment: As a customer you're licensed to use SDL Tridion, the exact terms of the licensing agreement vary, but yes, usually you will have developer licenses - if your license agreement covers it.

Answer (score 3):

You can build your own VM to explore if you are a SDL Tridion Partner or if you are working for a client needs. In both cases, you need the license (via either partner agreement/client license contract). Apart from Tridion license, you need to have license for non-tridion software (like VMware, Windows OS etc..)

Here is an article on How to build VM:
https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/creating-development-vm-1.aspx

Also, If you are partner you could talk to your SDL contact to see if you can get the sales VM Image.

Answer (score 1):

I've blogged similar (the same) thoughts as Chris and Nuno.

- [+1 to the Fifth Tridion Environment](http://www.createandbreak.net/2011/11/matching-software-licensing-to-sdlc.html#fifth)
- Read [How to get started](http://www.createandbreak.net/2011/11/how-to-get-to-play-with-sdl-tridion.html) for some leads on a Linked-In group and recruiters

Also consider [training](http://www.sdl.com/services/education-certification/training-product/) as at least a temporary way to get familiar with the software. SDL [sometimes offers discounts](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/05/train-and-untrained-which-are-you.html).